# Assignment Operator Overloading not invoking when accessing through pointers

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have an issue on operator overload in C++, Consider the following class

**CharacterString.h file**

```
class CharacterString {
 private:
   char* __charString;
 public:
   CharacterString();
   ~CharacterString();

void operator =(const char* sFileName);
};
```

//CharactorString.cpp file

```
CharacterString::CharacterString() { }

CharacterString::~CharacterString() { }


void CharacterString::operator=(const char* sFileName) 
{
   this->__charString = (char *)sFileName;
}
```

In the main function, the following code works fine.

```
CharacterString fileName;

fileName = "Hello, World";
```

However, the bellow code causing shows compiler error

```
CharacterString* fileName;

fileName = new CharacterString();
fileName = "Hello, World";
printf("%s", fileName);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdRsY.png)

Comment: If it did, how would you reassign the pointers themselves? Anyway, just dereference...

Comment: I understand, is there any syntax to do so.

Comment: @Gopinath `*fileName = "asd"` (you may want to [read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/))

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: While we're here, you should stop using `__` in your identifiers - all identifiers containing double underscore are reserved to the implementation for any purpose.  That includes macros which might silently change the meaning of your program.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare fileName as a pointer:

```
CharacterString* fileName;
```

Then if you want to access the object, you must first dereference it by using * or -> so:

```
*fileName = "Hello, World";
fileName->operator=("Hello, World");
```

The `printf()` call is completely incorrect and it works only by accident (because `CharacterString` object is put on the stack in the same binary format as `char *`). You should add a getter method for string:

```
class CharacterString {
private:
  char* __charString;
public:
  CharacterString();
  ~CharacterString();
  char *getString() { return __charString; }
  void operator =(const char* sFileName);
```

};

Then you can write:

```
printf("%s", fileName->getString());
```

Try to make e.g. `~CharacterString()` virtual to change the binary representation of the object and immediately it stops working without `getString()`.

Last (off topic), please note that symbols starting with underscores are reserved and should not be used in "user code".